# MySQL: Count rows of database so far per day

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm fairly new to SQL and PHP and have been burning my head over the following problem.

I'm looking for an SQL query (or in combination with PHP filtering) that could provide the following result: Basically a result for every day a row is added or removed + the amount of rows so far in that table.

Example:

```
2012-10-08 09:52:08    |   1 so far since beginning
2012-12-04 15:07:56    |   2 so far since beginning
2012-12-10 09:18:02    |   3 so far since beginning

...


2013-06-06 09:50:13    |   67 so far since beginning
2013-06-13 13:46:41    |   70 so far since beginning
2013-06-17 14:42:39    |   69 so far since beginning
2013-06-19 14:19:26    |   74 so far since beginning
2013-07-05 13:21:45    |   75 so far since beginning
```

Comment: So, you want the total number of rows that have been added and removed on a given day?

Comment: I want to create a list of how many rows there are in general on a certain day. For example, two days ago there were 69 rows, yesterday there were 74 rows, today there are 75 rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a GROUP BY to find today's records, and an subquery to find rows added before today. For instance,

```
SELECT DATE(t.datefield) AS date, COUNT(*) AS records_this_day, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable t2 WHERE t2.datefield < DATE(t.datefield)) AS records_before_this_day 
FROM mytable t GROUP BY DATE(t.datefield);
```

You will get results like this:

```
date        records_this_day records_before_this_day
2010-02-04  27               0
2010-02-05  2                27
2010-02-06  1                29
2010-02-07  1                30
```

But it is kinda slow. It may be better to just accumulate the value of records_this_day when you use this.

Edit: Obviously, if a row is deleted then history of that row is gone. So this may not be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) cnt
     , DATE(date_column) the_date
  from tbl
 group
    by date with rollup
```

note - if there are days without any entries, you will not get a row for that date in the result set from this sql query.

the [with rollup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) modifier will add a single row, which will be the count of all rows. You can identify that row because it will have a null value for `the_date`. Alternatively, omit the `with rollup` and just sum the cnt column yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To count entries in a database the query would be:

```
$query = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`
```

This query will SELECT every entry in your table, and will count rows

To handle the connection you can use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.rowcount.php) or [mysql_*](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-num-rows.php).

**I recommend you to use PDO** since mysql_* is depreceted and as the official documentation say:

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.

The code will look like this:

```
<?php
/** PDOs or MYSQL_* CONNECT HERE **/

echo date("Y-d-M h:m:s")."    |     ".$count." so far since beginning";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE date = ''";
```